# Which directory are request memoization, data cache and full route cache stored on server exactly?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, caching, react-server-components

I just started following nextjs's official tutorial and run into a problem with cache. I understand that nextjs's default behavior is to cache all the data, RSC payload and HTML. I have been referring to [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching). However, it does not mention which directory on the server the cache lives. This is my build folder[image: my build folder]

This is one of my route's page

```
import { Suspense } from "react";

async function ProductQuantity(){
  let res = await fetch("https://api.vercel.app/products/1");
  let data = await res.json();
  return <h1>{data.stock}</h1>
}

export default function Page(){
  return(
    <section>
      <h1>Product</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <ProductQuantity />
      </Suspense>
    </section>
  )
}
```

This is apparently an RSC. My understanding is during build time, cache should be generated under /build and I cannot find where it is.

The closest thing I can find under /build is a json file under /fetch-cache

```
    {"kind":"FETCH","data":{"headers":{"cache-control":"public, max-age=0, must-revalidate","connection":"keep-alive","content-encoding":"br","content-type":"application/json","date":"Sat, 24 Feb 2024 21:49:48 GMT","server":"Vercel","strict-transport-security":"max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload","transfer-encoding":"chunked","x-vercel-cache":"MISS","x-vercel-id":"pdx1::4cvln-1708811388089-e9b764356ae6"},"body":"eyJpZCI6MSwibmFtZSI6IlNtYXJ0cGhvbmUgWDIzIiwicHJpY2UiOjY5OS45OSwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJUaGUgbGF0ZXN0IGZsYWdzaGlwIHNtYXJ0cGhvbmUgd2l0aCBhIHN0dW5uaW5nIGRpc3BsYXkgYW5kIGFkdmFuY2VkIGNhbWVyYSBmZWF0dXJlcy4iLCJjYXRlZ29yeSI6IkVsZWN0cm9uaWNzIiwiYnJhbmQiOiJCcmFuZCBBIiwic3RvY2siOjUwfQ==","status":200,"url":"https://api.vercel.app/products/1"},"revalidate":31536000,"tags":[]}
```

However, it does not contain the number 50 which is the returned value of the fetch request.

Also, does nextjs's dev server also implement cache?

Thanks.

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBlSe8tvg4U) from vercel and still it does not explain where the cache is.